# SQL: Select Row with Last New Sequentially Distinct Value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

EDIT: Please see the updated question here: [SQL: Select Most Recent Sequentially Distinct Value w/ Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432069/sql-select-most-recent-sequentially-distinct-value-w-grouping)

I am having trouble writing a query that would select the last "new" sequentially distinct value. Since this is a bit ambiguous, here is an example to explain (assume row number is indicative of sequence; in my issue the rows are ordered by date):

```
|--------|-------|
| RowNum | Col A |
|--------|-------|
| 1      | A     |
| 2      | B     |
| 3      | C     |
| 4      | B     |
| 5      | A     |
| 6      | B     |
```

Would select:

```
| 6      | B     |
```

Although B also appears in rows 2 and 4, the fact that row 5 contains A means that the B in row 6 is sequentially distinct. But if table looked like this:

```
|--------|-------|
| RowNum | Col A |
|--------|-------|
| 1      | A     |
| 2      | B     |
| 3      | C     |
| 4      | B     |
| 5      | A     |
| 6      | A     | <--
```

Then we would want to select:

```
| 5      | A     |
```

I think that this would be an easier problem if I wasn't concerned with values being distinct but not sequential. I'm not really sure how to even consider sequence when making a query.

I have attempted to solve this by calculating the min/max row numbers where each value of Col A appears. That calculation (using the second sample table) would produce a result like this:

```
|--------|--------|--------|
| ColA   | MinRow | MaxRow |
|--------|--------|--------|
| A      | 1      | 6      |
| B      | 2      | 4      |
| C      | 3      | 3      |
```

However, this is where I get stuck, because although I can properly pick out A as the value to use, I don't know how to use the other rows in this table to recognize that we want A in row 5 (since it is interrupted by B at 4), not A in row 1...

Any help with this problem, if it is at all possible to do in SQL, would be greatly appreciated. I am running SQL 2008 SP4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by finding the previous RowNum of the row you want as result and then get the next Rownum:

```
select top 1 *
from tablename
where 
  RowNum > coalesce((
    select max(RowNum) from tablename where colA <> (
      select top 1 colA from tablename order by RowNum desc
    )
  ), 0) 
order by RowNum
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a720327f74e889bd9c4c8f6c11b38713).

Comment: I think this is a good solution and works well overall, however if there is only one row in the table, it will return nothing. I accepted it as the answer regardless b/c I guess that's just a conditional I'd have to check beforehand?

Comment: Try it now with only 1 row.

Comment: Yep, seems to work as expected now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Replace 0 with -1 if 0 is a valid RowNum in your table.

Comment: *if all ColA's in table are the same, it will return all rows* no it will not. This is why I use `top 1`. It returns only 1 row. See the last example in this:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8fdac494deb9ccbcf18bb29c442435c

Comment: Oh yeah that's my fault, I took that one out trying to figure out the grouped operation.

Comment: As for the other column, if you want to apply the same logic only to this column, you can change the name of the column in the code. If the logic is different then post a question with all the relevant data and explain what you need.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect my question about grouping.

Comment: This is not how it works. You can't ask a new question with different requirements inside another question. Post a new question including everything needed.